# SQL: will SERIABLIZABLE insert visable to other non-serizable transaction

Tags: mysql, database, transactions

Let's say, we have transaction t1 who inserts a row into a table at SERIABLIZABLE level. Now there is another transaction t2 who is not at SERIABLIZABLE level and it selects all rows from the same table by select * from table_foo

My question is before t1 commit/release the lock, will t2 see the row insert by t1?

Comment: It will not as far as I know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is before t1 commit/release the lock, will t2 see the row
>   insert by t1?

What t2 sees depends entirely on the isolation level of t2. It has nothing to do with the isolation level of t1.

To see how it works, open two terminal windows, and make two connections to a MySQL database.  Assume the table "test" exists, and has two rows.

```
Term 1                                         Term 2
set transaction isolation level serializable;  
                                               set transaction isolation level read uncommitted;
                                               select count(*) as num_rows from test;
                                               +----------+
                                               | num_rows |
                                               +----------+
                                               |        2 |
                                               +----------+
                                               1 row in set (0.00 sec)

start transaction;
insert into test values 
('2013-01-02 08:00', '2013-01-02 08');
                                               select count(*) as num_rows from test;
                                               +----------+
                                               | num_rows |
                                               +----------+
                                               |        3 |
                                               +----------+
                                               1 row in set (0.00 sec)

rollback;
                                               select count(*) as num_rows from test;
                                               +----------+
                                               | num_rows |
                                               +----------+
                                               |        2 |
                                               +----------+
                                               1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

To make sure Term 2 *doesn't* see the uncommitted rows from Term 1's INSERT statement until they're committed, use any isolation level besides READ UNCOMMITTED in Term 2.

Comment: Thanks! I did the experiment as well, and it proved what you said :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that T1 executes before T2; T2 will not see the rows because T2 waits for T1.

When T1 starts to execute, It locks the table to assure the maximun isolation level which means that no other transaction will execute on this table until T1 completes.

If any other transaction try to use the table (in this case T2), it will have to wait.

Therefore, T1 and T2  will never execute at the same time (concurrently).
e.g.:

T2 waits for T1

when T1 completes T2 executes

T2 will see the rows inserted by T1

---

(It's too long for comments area)
Yes, if you really need execute each transaction in a secuential way the alternative could be to set SERIALIZABLE as database's isolation level.

Theorically each transaction should to execute in isolation (for achieving the I of ACID properties) but in practice this has not much sense. It's all about a performance issue. A high concurrency application's database could not execute properly in this way.

The idea is to achieve balancing between isolation and performance. When the isolation level is decreased (e.g. COMMITTED READ that generally is the default isolation level) some kind of problems can appear: lost updates, non-repetable read, phantom read. Usually this risk is acceptable and it can be also controlled rising the isolation level only at certain transactions that have to deal with these situations.

Comment: Do you mean the sql use a mandatory lock when a transaction is at isolation level? Since T2 may operate at the very low isolation level, say "Read uncommitted", then it won't try to lock the table, so I am not sure T2 will be blocked.

Comment: Well, if T2 is running with "Read uncommitted" isolation level, yes, T2 will execute and it will read the data inserted by T1. "Read uncommitted" turns off the concurrency checking described above. I should have mentioned that in my answer ;)

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. So basically in order to achieve the "serialization", all related transactions need to be at SERIALIZABLE level, right?